# Extracting the remaining substring out of square brackets in a sentence using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a sentence of this kind: `[amenities FREE HOT BREAKFAST AND WIRELESS INTERNET]`

I want to extract the sub-string `FREE HOT BREAKFAST AND WIRELESS INTERNET` from the square brackets.

I have tried this Regex `\[(.*?)\]` which is giving me the entire sub-string inside the square bracket.

[image: Tried Regex]

I have also tried the Regex `\bamenities\b` to get the word Amenities and tried to negate the string around it.

[image: Tried Regex 2]

But, I want the rest of the substring apart from the substring `'Amenities'` at the start. I want to extract all the possible substrings in square brackets which is preceded by the word `'Amenities'`.

I am trying this code to extract the following in C#.

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "BEST AVAILABLE RATE , [amenities BREAKFAST] , [amenities WIFI] AND FITN ? - MORE IN HP";

            MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(s, @"\bamenities\b");

            foreach(var item in m)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);

        }
    }
```

Below is what is expected

```
   Input: BEST AVAILABLE RATE , [amenities BREAKFAST] , [amenities WIFI] AND FITN ? - MORE IN HP 

    Output: 
    string 1 - BREAKFAST 
    string 2 - WIFI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=amenities )+[^\]]*
```

This uses the `lookbehind` assertion, which helps replacing `\K`

[Check the result here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Damenities%20%29%2B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*&i=BEST%20AVAILABLE%20RATE%20%2C%20%5Bamenities%20BREAKFAST%5D%20%2C%20%5Bamenities%20WIFI%5D%20AND%20FITN%20%3F%20-%20MORE%20IN%20HP&r=x)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/rHhZB7/1).

```
/\[amenities (.*?)\]/ig
```

Comment: `string s = "BEST AVAILABLE RATE , [amenities BREAKFAST] , [amenities WIFI] AND FITN ? - MORE IN HP";
            
            MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(s, @"/\[amenities (.*?)\]/ig");
            
            foreach(var item in m)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);`  I don't seem to get any output in this code I tried. But in the [Regex 101 site](https://regex101.com/) I am getting full match

Comment: Change you C# code like this: `MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[amenities (.*?)\]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); `

Comment: Yeah in this case, I am getting the entire word inside the square bracket like before `Index=22, Value=[amenities BREAKFAST]
Index=46, Value=[amenities WIFI]`

Comment: You need to modify c# code. `foreach(Match item in m) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Groups[1].Value);
  }`